# Async delegate callbacks not fully executing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, delegates, async-await

I have an async method `MyActionAsync`, which receives as a parameter an async `Func<int, Task>` as a callback.

The method calls the asyncCallback correctly, but it steps over that step before all the `await` from the asynCallback have been executed.

This creates some big problems for me.

How / what can i use to make sure that the like `await asyncCallback(id)` will step over only when the asyncCallback has completely executed.

```
public class MyService
{
    public async Task<int> MyActionAsync(int id, Func<int, Task> asyncCallback)
    {
        // 1. do something

        // 2. execute the callback function
        // Steps over this step after the first await is finished, and not when all of them are finished
        await asyncCallback(id);

        // 3. return
        return id;
    }
}

async Task Test()
{
    Func<int, Task> asyncCallback =
        async (id) =>
        {
            var products = await _unitOfWork.Products.Where(p => p.UserId == id).ToListAsync();
            var pictures = await _unitOfWork.Pictures.Where(p => p.UserId == id).ToListAsync();
        };

    MyService service = new MyService();

    await service.MyActionAsync(1, asyncCallback);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that no exceptions occur ?

Comment: what makes you think that `asyncCallback` is not completed?

Comment: Indeed, I had an error on one of the lines inside the asyncCallback and that was the reason it didn't evaluate it completely..my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems ok

It should wait for the asyncCallback to be finnished

How do you know it does not wait for it to be over?

Maybe it seems like it's not waiting till it's over because the debugger wont step into the Func when you press F11, it will step into only if you put a breakpoint inside

Another thing you should check is if an exception is thrown from inside the Func

Comment: I actually had an error inside the asyncCallback and this was the reason it didn't evaluated all the await lines

Answer (score 0):

An `async` method returns when after encounters an `await` statement and sets up the asynchronous operation being awaited. The rest of the method then continues after the `await` is finished.

I don't believe you can step through `async` methods like that, but if you put in some `Console.WriteLine` statements you should see what you expect.